# Iterate over object property with same name

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I have an array of objects, and each object might include properties that are named the same. How do I iterate over the objects property to extract each entry?

I've tried the code below but it only gives me the last property in the object. Any ideas?

```js
var clearingnumberz = [{
    "Namn": "Nordea",
    "Clearingnummer": "1100-1199",
    "Clearingnummer": "1400-2099",
    "Clearingnummer": "3000-3399",
    "Clearingnummer": "3410-4999"
  },
  {
    "Namn": "Danske Bank",
    "Clearingnummer": "1200-1399",
    "Clearingnummer": "9180-9189"
  },
  {
    "Namn": "Handelsbanken",
    "Clearingnummer": "6000-6999"
  },
  {
    "Namn": "JP Nordiska",
    "Clearingnummer": "2300-2309"
  }
];


function SearchForBankName() {

  var userInput = document.getElementById("bankTxt").value;

  for (var bank in clearingnumberz) {

    var currentObject = clearingnumberz[bank];

    if (userInput === currentObject.Namn) {

      for (var clearingnumber in currentObject) {
        console.log(currentObject.Clearingnummer);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='bankTxt' placeholder="search a value in Bank" value="Handelsbanken">
<input type="button" onclick="SearchForBankName()" value="search">
```

Comment: it is not valid javascript with the same key in an object.

Comment: objects  can not have duplicate keys

Comment: keep value as array for properties with multiple values, eg: "Clearingnummer": ["1400-2099", "1400-4099", "1600-2129"],

Comment: you can use `forEach` on object to get `key` and `value` both for properties of object.

Comment: THanks for the array-tip, that seems like a good solution. I split the intervals in to two strings to be able to search through the interval 1400-2099. Can you do this easily on an array aswell? :O

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. JavaScript objects may not have properties with the same name. So your objects don't actually look like that.

```js
const obj = {
  "Namn": "Nordea",
  "Clearingnummer": "1100-1199",
  "Clearingnummer": "1400-2099",
  "Clearingnummer": "3000-3399",
  "Clearingnummer": "3410-4999"
}

console.log(obj); // oops
```

In short, you can't do what you want. You have to change the way your data is modeled.

Answer (score 1):

Fo a faster access, you could convert your data (with arrays) to a hash table and get the name with the number as key.

```js
var clearingnumberz = [{ namn: "Nordea", clearingnummer: ["1100-1199", "1400-2099", "3000-3399", "3410-4999"] }, { namn: "Danske Bank", clearingnummer: ["1200-1399", "9180-9189"] }, { namn: "Handelsbanken", clearingnummer: ["6000-6999"] }, { namn: "JP Nordiska", clearingnummer: ["2300-2309"] }],
    numberz = Object.create(null);

clearingnumberz.forEach(function (bank) {
    bank.clearingnummer.forEach(function (clearingnumber) {
        numberz[clearingnumber] = bank.namn;
    });
});

console.log(numberz['6000-6999']);
console.log(numberz);
```